# Ignore connection error on OBDC query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that that connects to several remote machines to union data into a single table.  It works fine when all the machines are connected but occasionally any given machine may be turned off (which results in error), I'd like my query to ignore any connections that are unavailable and continue with the rest of the query.  Is there any way to do this?

I'm using linked tables with an OBDC conncetion (driver: MySql ODBC 5.3 Ansi Driver)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT "HX32" AS workcenter, "HX32." & [HX32].[dataid] AS tbldataid, HX32.dataid AS dataid, HX32.TS, DMin("[TS]","[HX32]","[TS] > #" & [TS] & "#") AS EndTS, DateDiff("s",[TS],EndTS) AS durationsec, Format(Int([durationsec]/86400)) & " " & Format([durationsec]/86400,"hh:nn:ss") AS duration, Format(TS,"mm/dd/yyyy") AS [Day], Switch(incycle=0,'Down',incycle=1,'Running') AS Status
FROM HX32
WHERE (((HX32.TS)>Date()-3) AND ((HX32.incycle)=0))

UNION ALL 

SELECT "VL65A" AS workcenter, "VL65A." & [VL65A].[dataid] AS tbldataid, VL65A.dataid AS dataid, VL65A.TS, DMin("[TS]","[VL65A]","[TS] > #" & [TS] & "#") AS EndTS, DateDiff("s",[TS],EndTS) AS durationsec, Format(Int([durationsec]/86400)) & " " & Format([durationsec]/86400,"hh:nn:ss") AS duration, Format(TS,"mm/dd/yyyy") AS [Day], Switch(incycle=0,'Down',incycle=1,'Running') AS Status
FROM VL65A
WHERE (((VL65A.TS)>Date()-3) AND ((VL65A.incycle)=0))

UNION ALL 

SELECT "VL68B" AS workcenter, "VL68B." & [VL68B].[dataid] AS tbldataid, VL68B.dataid AS dataid, VL68B.TS, DMin("[TS]","[VL68B]","[TS] > #" & [TS] & "#") AS EndTS, DateDiff("s",[TS],EndTS) AS durationsec, Format(Int([durationsec]/86400)) & " " & Format([durationsec]/86400,"hh:nn:ss") AS duration, Format(TS,"mm/dd/yyyy") AS [Day], Switch(incycle=0,'Down',incycle=1,'Running') AS Status
FROM VL68B
WHERE (((VL68B.TS)>Date()-3) AND ((VL68B.incycle)=0))
;
```

Comment: This can't be done using only a query. You will have to use some VBA to test if all machines are on, and then dynamically generate the queries SQL.

Comment: @Erik,  I was hoping I could do it w/o VBA but if that's the only option I think I can come up with a solution

Comment: Well, queries are just SQL, they don't have any logic beyond rows or error detection in Access. There's no such thing as stored procedures here, so any more complex things will fail (you can do `CREATE PROCEDURE` but that just creates a query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using VBA to solve per @Erik's comments:

It loops through each connection checks it, if connection is good it modifies a query and runs.

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim canConnect As Boolean
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim conctns As Variant
Dim conctn As Variant

conctns = Array("HX32", "VL65A", "VL68B")

For Each conctn In conctns

    On Error GoTo sub_error

    cnn.Open conctn
    If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
        canConnect = True

        strSQL = "SELECT '" & conctn & "' AS workcenter, '" & conctn & ".' & [" & conctn & "].[dataid] AS tbldataid, " & conctn & ".dataid AS dataid, " & conctn & ".TS, DMin('[TS]','[" & conctn & "]','[TS] > #' & [TS] & '#') AS EndTS, DateDiff('s',[TS],EndTS) AS durationsec, Format(Int([durationsec]/86400)) & ' ' & Format([durationsec]/86400,'hh:nn:ss') AS duration, Format(TS,'mm/dd/yyyy') AS [Day], Switch(incycle=0,'Down',incycle=1,'Running') AS Status FROM " & conctn & " WHERE (((" & conctn & ".TS)>Date()-3) AND ((" & conctn & ".incycle)=0));"
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs("unionall").SQL = strSQL
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "appendall", acViewNormal, acEdit
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "splithours", acViewNormal, acEdit

        MsgBox conctn & " updated: " & canConnect
        cnn.Close

    End If

sub_error:
  MsgBox conctn & ": " & Error$
  Resume sub_error_exit
sub_error_exit:
Next conctn
```